# Sometimes I get weird sound issues

Tags: 20.04, sound

Sometimes I get weird sound issues. It seems like as the sound quality would be very bad.
It mostly happens when watching videos.

Restarting that specific software (mostly Firefox) fixes this issue.

Is that a known thing and someone could help me with that?